# SSRS - Month not starting on correct day

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to make a report that generates a calendar for each month where the user can specify a range of months and years. My matrix has a column grouping on `Weekday` and the row grouping is on `WeekNumber` (see query results below).

[image]

The issue I'm stuck on is that the day is starting in the wrong place **as shown below:**

[image]

This is because my query only takes in the days from that particular month and not the few days from the month before and after that would normally be grayed out on a calendar:

[image]

Although I suspect this problem may also be solvable in the matrix itself I'm not sure if solving it in the query or solving it in the matrix would be better than the other.

**My current query:**

```
SELECT  t1.[TimeSheetLineID] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetID] ,
        t1.[JobID] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetDate] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetCreatedOn] ,
        t1.[TimeSheetLastModifiedOn] ,
        t1.[StartTime] ,
        t1.[EndTime] ,
        t1.[TotalTime] ,
        t1.[EmployeeName] ,
        t2.DateFull ,
        t2.[FullYear] ,
        t2.[WeekNumber] ,
        t2.[WeekDay] ,
        t2.[WeekDayName] ,
        t2.[MonthDay] ,
        t2.[MonthName] ,
        t2.[MonthNumber]
FROM    dbo.DateLookup t2
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[FactTimeSheets] t1 
  ON t1.TimeSheetDate = t2.DateFull
  AND (t1.JobID = @jobNumber) 
WHERE (t2.FullYear = @year) 
  AND (t2.MonthNumber BETWEEN @startMonth AND @endMonth)
ORDER BY FullYear, MonthNumber, MonthDay, WeekDay
```

**Current query result (notice `WeekDay` starts with 2 for the month of Aug):**
[image]

Based off [this article](http://msdyn.blogspot.com/2013/07/create-calendar-style-reports-in-sql.html).

**--UPDATE--**

I'm using the CTE in my query below to get the extra dates I need to fill out this calendar. I tested it on the Date table and will update my answer tomorrow with the final query:

```
DECLARE @year INT ,
    @startMonth DATE ,
    @endMonth DATE;
SET @year = '2016';
SET @startMonth = '2016-08-01';
SET @endMonth = '2016-08-31';

DECLARE @StartDate DATE ,
    @EndDate DATE;
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(s, 0, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @startMonth), 0));
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) + 1, @StartDate);
--SELECT @StartDate

SET @EndDate = DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @startMonth) + 1, 0));
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @EndDate), @EndDate)
--SELECT @EndDate;
;

WITH    Dates ( [Date] )
          AS (
   --Select First day in range
               SELECT   CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate) AS [Date]
               UNION ALL
   --Add a record for every day in the range
               SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
               FROM     Dates
               WHERE    Date < CONVERT(DATETIME, @EndDate)
             ),
        Events
          AS ( SELECT   [FullYear] ,
                        [DateFull] ,
                        [WeekNumber] ,
                        [WeekDay] ,
                        [WeekDayName] ,
                        [MonthDay] ,
                        [MonthName] ,
                        [MonthNumber]
               FROM     [dbo].[DateLookup]
             )
    SELECT  e.[FullYear] ,
            e.[DateFull] ,
            d.[Date] ,
            e.[WeekNumber] ,
            e.[WeekDay] ,
            e.[WeekDayName] ,
            e.[MonthDay] ,
            e.[MonthName] ,
            e.[MonthNumber]
    FROM    Dates d
            LEFT JOIN Events e ON d.[Date] = CAST(e.DateFull AS DATE)
    GROUP BY FullYear ,
            MonthNumber ,
            DateFull ,
            d.[Date] ,
            WeekNumber ,
            MonthName ,
            WeekDayName ,
            MonthDay ,
            WeekDay
    ORDER BY Date;
```

**--FINAL UPDATED QUERY--**

I hope this helps someone in the future.

```
SET @startDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, CAST(CAST(@year AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@startMonth AS varchar) + '-01' AS DATETIME)), 0);
SET @startDate = DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate) + 1, @startDate);

SET @endDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, CAST(CAST(@year AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@endMonth AS varchar) + '-01' AS DATETIME)) + 1, 0);
SET @endDate = DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @endDate), @endDate);

WITH    Dates ( [Date] )
          AS ( SELECT   CONVERT(DATETIME, @startDate) AS [Date]
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
               FROM     Dates
               WHERE    Date < CONVERT(DATETIME, @endDate)
             ),
        Events
          AS ( SELECT   t1.[TimeSheetLineID] ,
                        t1.[TimeSheetID] ,
                        t1.[JobID] ,
                        t1.[TimeSheetDate] ,
                        t1.[TimeSheetCreatedOn] ,
                        t1.[TimeSheetLastModifiedOn] ,
                        t1.[StartTime] ,
                        t1.[EndTime] ,
                        t1.[TotalTime] ,
                        t1.[EmployeeName] ,
                        t1.[CostCategory] ,
                        t2.[DateFull] ,
                        t2.[FullYear] ,
                        t2.[WeekNumber] ,
                        t2.[WeekDay] ,
                        t2.[WeekDayName] ,
                        t2.[MonthDay] ,
                        t2.[MonthName] ,
                        t2.[MonthNumber]
               FROM     dbo.DateLookup t2
                        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[FactTimeSheets] t1 ON t1.TimeSheetDate = t2.DateFull
                                                              AND ( t1.JobID = @jobNumber )
               WHERE    ( t2.FullYear = @year )
             )
    SELECT  e.[TimeSheetLineID] ,
            e.[TimeSheetID] ,
            e.[JobID] ,
            e.[TimeSheetDate] ,
            e.[TimeSheetCreatedOn] ,
            e.[TimeSheetLastModifiedOn] ,
            e.[StartTime] ,
            e.[EndTime] ,
            e.[TotalTime] ,
            e.[EmployeeName] ,
            e.[CostCategory] ,
            e.[DateFull] ,
            d.[Date] ,
            e.[FullYear] ,
            e.[WeekNumber] ,
            e.[WeekDay] ,
            e.[WeekDayName] ,
            e.[MonthDay] ,
            e.[MonthName] ,
            e.[MonthNumber]
    FROM    Dates d
            LEFT JOIN Events e ON d.[Date] = CAST(e.DateFull AS DATE)
    ORDER BY Date;
```

Comment: You could return a flag along with each day that indicates if it should be grayed out or not. I had this problem too. You may have to include a few days in the previous and next month to even out your calendar.

Comment: Hi @RossBush, did you fix this in your query or did you do it somehow in the matrix? Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I returned the Monday or Sunday, however you have your first day of week configured, as the first day of the range and then calculated the last day of the month and added any spillover days of the last day's week. So if the last day was a Tuesday then I returned Sunday of that week as the last day of the range so I could add spillover grey effect. However, you need to flag the spillover days in your query so you can color them gray in the matrix.

Comment: In the query the CalendarBlockNumber was not necessarily the DayNumberInMonth.

Comment: Can you use a CTE to union with your month in order to pad it with the last days of the previous and first days of the next month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the dates in a matrix to get the layout right.

Insert a matrix. Group and sort the columns by weekday (number). Group and sort the rows by week number. It should look like this:

[image]

Now when you run it it will come out like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi @StevenWhite, thanks for your answer and I updated my question to show that this was what I had but my matrix came out differently. Could you update your answer to show the query you used for this result?

Comment: How were you able to get the values to move over? Did you use any group expressions or anything else?

Comment: @JonathanPorter There's nothing special about the query. As long as you are grouping and sorting on the week number and day number it should come out right. If you're really grouping on weekday, 1 can't be in the Monday column. Your raw query results look correct.

Comment: I was missing the sorting in my grouping. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Final answer:**

```
SET @startDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, CAST(CAST(@year AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@startMonth AS varchar) + '-01' AS DATETIME)), 0);
SET @startDate = DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate) + 1, @startDate);

SET @endDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, CAST(CAST(@year AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@endMonth AS varchar) + '-01' AS DATETIME)) + 1, 0);
SET @endDate = DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @endDate), @endDate);

WITH    Dates ( [Date] )
          AS ( SELECT   CONVERT(DATETIME, @startDate) AS [Date]
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
               FROM     Dates
               WHERE    Date < CONVERT(DATETIME, @endDate)
             ),
        Events
          AS ( SELECT   t1.[TimeSheetLineID] ,
                        t1.[TimeSheetID] ,
                        t1.[JobID] ,
                        t1.[TimeSheetDate] ,
                        t1.[TimeSheetCreatedOn] ,
                        t1.[TimeSheetLastModifiedOn] ,
                        t1.[StartTime] ,
                        t1.[EndTime] ,
                        t1.[TotalTime] ,
                        t1.[EmployeeName] ,
                        t1.[CostCategory] ,
                        t2.[DateFull] ,
                        t2.[FullYear] ,
                        t2.[WeekNumber] ,
                        t2.[WeekDay] ,
                        t2.[WeekDayName] ,
                        t2.[MonthDay] ,
                        t2.[MonthName] ,
                        t2.[MonthNumber]
               FROM     dbo.DateLookup t2
                        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[FactTimeSheets] t1 ON t1.TimeSheetDate = t2.DateFull
                                                              AND ( t1.JobID = @jobNumber )
               WHERE    ( t2.FullYear = @year )
             )
    SELECT  e.[TimeSheetLineID] ,
            e.[TimeSheetID] ,
            e.[JobID] ,
            e.[TimeSheetDate] ,
            e.[TimeSheetCreatedOn] ,
            e.[TimeSheetLastModifiedOn] ,
            e.[StartTime] ,
            e.[EndTime] ,
            e.[TotalTime] ,
            e.[EmployeeName] ,
            e.[CostCategory] ,
            e.[DateFull] ,
            d.[Date] ,
            e.[FullYear] ,
            e.[WeekNumber] ,
            e.[WeekDay] ,
            e.[WeekDayName] ,
            e.[MonthDay] ,
            e.[MonthName] ,
            e.[MonthNumber]
    FROM    Dates d
            LEFT JOIN Events e ON d.[Date] = CAST(e.DateFull AS DATE)
    ORDER BY Date;
```

Answer (score -1):

August 1st is Monday so the weekday should be 1. But it's 2 in your table

Comment: Hi Sepehr, you're looking at WeekDay not MonthDay. Sunday is considered the beginning of the week (1) which is why Monday is = 2. But MonthDay shows that it is the beginning date of that particular month.